# The Difference Between “Extensible” and “Pluggable” Applications

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, system

I misunderstand between “Extensible” and “Pluggable” terms . Can anyone explain for me ?

Comment: These terms are a bit slippery.  They are both closely related, but they tend to mean slightly different ways of going about the same task.  The task is to add behavior to something after it is built.  Extensions and plugins take two different approaches.  See my answer below for the best attempt at defining the differences of the approach.

Answer (score 4):

From Practical coder view:

Extensible - get some code class and build on top of this class using it as base. A sealed class is not extensible by inheritance. But extensibility can be achieved in other ways as long as code in your original class is reusable.

Pluggable - can also be extensible. What makes things pluggable is the ability of just dropping something (dll) somewhere and have that thing working. It is achieved by your pluggable item having adhere to certain rules (implement interface).

Depends how you look at it, the definition differ. For example, your plugins can extend an application. But from the coding perspective, extensibility is literally, buliding something in such way that you can take it later and make something else out of it. And pluggability is a design in which you don't know what your components are but you know how they will work not matter what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Extensible means that you can configure a module (or framework component) to eventually do what you want.

Pluggable means that you can remove the module, perhaps substituting in your own.  That module  will be fully under your control, and should eventually do what you want.

A good example:

> Warcraft maps are extensible.  You can create new maps, but you cannot
>   really remove water tiles, you just avoid using them.  Similarly, you cannot 
>   redefine where the elements must fit in the file, perhaps to save space.
>
> Web plugins are pluggable.  You can create a new web plugin, but you
>   do not need to copy *any* code from another plugin, nor do you need to
>   follow any internal format.  You do need to follow the plugin
>   *interface* which will be the only line of communication between the application 
>   and your plugin.  Two popular web plugins are the Adobe Acrobat PDF reader and the
>   Java Applet Runner.

To a degree, these are conceptual items.  It may be possible to think of plugins as extension points, thus making all plugins *extensions* and the plugin system an *extensible* one; however, in programming terminology, extensible interfaces tend to be less flexible than plugin interfaces.

Likewise, you might think of your configuration for an extension point to "plug into" the application; but, unlike a plugin, an extension cannot generally be used outside of the application it is an "extension of".